# Pandas from json exploding with the custom prefix

Tags: pandas

On input i have pandas dataframe with nested columns/values.
I do run

```
json_struct = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_struct)
```

This way i explode/flatten columns. It's working fine.

The point is: i wanted to add new columns with non default prefix (currently flattened columns are with '.' character, while i want '_').

Example: instead of getting column `level1.level2.level3` i want to get column `level1_level2_level3`.

I've tried to pass `record_prefix` or `meta_prefix` argument to pd.io.json.json_normalize but it does not work.
Any hint how to do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `sep` parameter to the desired one:

> **sep : *str, default ‘.’***
>
> ```
> Nested records will generate names separated by sep. e.g., for sep=’.’, {‘foo’: {‘bar’: 0}} -> foo.bar.
> ```

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json_struct, sep='_')
```